# My LinkedList is not saved as it should be (regarding its elements order)

Tags: java, jpa

First of all, pardon me for my poor english level. I will try to be as understandable as I can.

I am trying to re-order a playlist of music files. A Playlist is basically a `LinkedList<MusicFiles>` with a name.
I change the position of an element, it seems to be as it should, cool. But when  I save it in the database the order doesn't change! I am doing something wrong, that's a fact, but after hours spent debugging, my mind could really use a debugger for itself...

Here is my jsf code (inside a p:datatable):

```html
<p:commandButton title="Move Down" 
                 ajax="false" 
                 image="down" 
                 action="#{playlistMBean.increasePosition(musicFile.URL)}"  
                 onclick="show_my_playlists?face-redirect=true"/>
```

The backing bean code:

```java
@Named(value = "playlistMBean")
@SessionScoped
public class PlaylistMBean implements Serializable {
    @EJB
    private PlaylistManager playlistManager;
    private Playlist currentPlaylist;
    //...

    public void increasePosition(String musicURL) {
        currentPlaylist.increasePosition(musicURL);
        playlistManager.save(currentPlaylist);
    }

    //...
}
```

"currentPlaylist" is obviously a Playlist, so here's the code of the method in the entity bean "Playlist":

```java
@Entity
@NamedQueries(/*...*/)
public class Playlist implements Serializable  {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(cascade= {CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE},fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
    @OrderBy(/* ??????????? */
    private LinkedList<MusicFile> musicList;

    private String name;

    //...

    public void increasePosition(String url) {
        if (url != null) {
            MusicFile mf = getMusicFileByURL(url);
            int position = getPosition(url);
            if (position < musicList.size() - 1) {
                musicList.remove(position);
                musicList.add(position + 1, mf);
            }
         }
     }
```

And finally the code of the playlist manager which should save the reordered playlist in the database:

```java
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class PlaylistManager {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "Doozer-ejbPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public void save(Playlist playlist) {
        Playlist p = em.find(Playlist.class, playlist.getId());
        if (p != null) {
            em.merge(playlist);
        }
        else {
            em.persist(playlist);    
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

The given playlist in this last step is the good one (reordered). So my guess is that my problem is with the entity manager (I'm such a genius, I know...).

Does anyone know why?

May it comes from the cascade type? Due to my lack of knowledge about it I'm not sure which one should I put. I have tried `CascadeType.ALL` but then it raises exception when adding music files. `CascadeType.DETACH` was my first choice since I dont't want to delete the musics when deleting a playlist... But here again I really don't know for sure if I know what I'm talking about :(

[Edit]: Thanks to Piotr Nowicki, my question has changed quite a lot: how can I define the `@OrderBy` annotation in order to sort the `LinkedList` according to its inner order? Is it even possible? The easy/ugly method would be to add a property `position` to the `MusicFile` entity but I'd rather not.

Comment: How is your entity annotated? Do you have any `@OrderColumn` or `@OrderBy` annotations?

Comment: I've just edited my post so it now should answer your question -> the entity does not have any annotation dealing with its order... But the list is "directly" saved so should be its inner order, shouldn't it?

Comment: Thanks to your post, Piotr, and after a little more digging, it seems you had the correct intuition!!! Without any `@OrderBy` annotation the elements are sorted according to their id => Do you know how to define the sort order on a list property? I wouldn't like to add a property `position` to the music entity, but if I have to...

Comment: did you try adding the `@OrderColumn` on the list property? It should automatically add an appropriate column.

Comment: My hero........ I let you answer it: it solved my problem and saved my day! ;)

Comment: <awkward_face> ;-) So if it worked, lets create an answer from the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to preserve the order in which elements in `List` are stored in the database (and further retrieved from it) you should use `@OrderBy` or `@OrderColumn` annotations.

In your case, if you just want the `List` to be returned in order without any advanced conditions, the `@OrderColumn` should be sufficient:

```
@OneToMany(...)
@OrderColumn
private LinkedList<MusicFile> musicList;
```

Comment: `OrdemColumn` requires JPA 2.0. it uses an extra field on the database to main order information, I think you should use a position extra field and let your persistence provider update it accordingly when you reorder your `List`. Here's a good sumary about the subject: [EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/2.0/OrderColumns](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/2.0/OrderColumns).

Comment: To be clear: `@OrderColumn(name="POSITION")`, no need for anything else.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly yes, it's JPA 2.0 feature; I guess the rest of your comment (about extra position field in the model) refers to JPA 1.0? Also you don't need to specify the `@OrderColumn` name attribute, as the JPA-provider can provide you a default one (in 'propertyName_ORDER' format)

Comment: I meant extra column not field lol :D. It still requires an extra column in the database for JPA 2.0, you can let it apply the defaults as @Piotr mentioned, but I guess It makes more sense to call it position. It will use that column to maintain the `List` inner order as you require.

Comment: Thanks again Piotr, and thanks Anthony for this information! `@OrderColumn` should be sufficient in my case: it creates a column named "MUSICLIST_ORDER". Meaningful enough.